# application.property error message "does not map to any root"

Tags: quarkus

I have a problem with my quarkus configuration

File `./config/application.properties`

```
liquido.frontend-url=http://localhost:3001
liquido.jwt.expirationSecs=3600
liquido.jwt.secret=jwtSecret
liquido.login-link-expiration-hours=24
```

I would like to map this to an object as described here :https://quarkus.io/guides/config-mappings

`LiquidoConfig.java`

```
@ConfigMapping(prefix = "liquido")
public interface LiquidoConfig {

    String frontendUrl();

    int loginLinkExpirationHours();

    public interface Jwt {
        public String secret();
        public Long expirationSecs();
    }
}
```

But I do get the error message

```
2023-03-27 20:37:39,609 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application (with profile [dev]): io.smallrye.config.ConfigValidationException: Configuration validation failed:
    liquido.jwt.secret does not map to any root
    liquido.jwt.expirationSecs does not map to any root
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a property of type `LiquidoConfig.JWT` in your `LiquidoConfig`

```
@ConfigMapping(prefix = "liquido")
public interface LiquidoConfig {
  String frontendUrl();
  int loginLinkExpirationHours();
  Jwt jwt();
   
  public interface Jwt {
    String secret();
    Long expirationSecs();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. I missed this additional neccessary attribute in the docs.